# creating docID for each text file in folder

Tags: python, elasticsearch, file-io, nlp, data-science

hello I have a folder with name dict and that folder contains 4 to 6 text files, now I wanted to assign a ID docID to each text file in folder and I have used the code below

```
docID_list = [int(docID_string) for docID_string in os.listdir('/Users/suryavamsi/dict')]
```

and I have got an error

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10:
```

I have tried lots of ways but couldn't crack it can any one help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to convert strings to integers.
That will only work if your strings look like integers (e.g. `'1'`).

If you just want an integer value associated with each file, use `enumerate`:

```
docID_list = [i for i, _ in enumerate(os.listdir('/Users/suryavamsi/dict'))]
```

Or just:

```
docID_list = list(range(len(os.listdir('/Users/suryavamsi/dict'))))
```

You might want to keep a `dict` that maps `docID` to filename, in which case you can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
docID_list = {i:doc for i, doc in enumerate(os.listdir('/Users/suryavamsi/dict'))}
```